# Differences between using synchronized(obj) and a declared lock

Tags: java, multithreading, object, synchronization, locking

I'm trying to synchronize this run() method. I would like that only one thread at time enters in it, but I don't understand why the solution tells me to use the **synchronized(obj)** method:

```
public Tabellina(Contatore o, int num) {
    obj = o; 
    numero = num;
    r = new Random(); 
    start();
}

public void run() {
    synchronized(obj) {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            obj.incr();
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + obj.getVal());
        }
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(2000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }}
}
```

My idea was to create a lock and synchronized it on this way:

```
public Tabellina(Contatore o, int num) {
    obj = o; 
    numero = num;
    r = new Random(); 
    l1 = new ReentrantLock();
    start();
}

public synchronized void run() {
    l1.lock();
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            obj.incr();
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + obj.getVal());
        }
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(2000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    l1.unlock();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't works because the threads prints the content of the for alternately. How is it possible? If I use the lock() at the start of the run method shouldn't the first thread complete the for and then release the lock and let the second thread enters in the method?

Comment: I think you create two independent locks. I presume that "Contatore o" is the same for all threads. However, you have a different "l1" for each thread, and thus locks don't work. Use one lock object for all threads.

Comment: (maybe) because you synchronize (multiple) threads over (one/the same) Cantatore....but with individual locks..? (Every thread has his own lock... :) ...you will get the same results, when you use a "shared lock"! (you should make the lock `static`, or also pass it in via constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
public synchronized void run() {
```

is short hand for

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
```

As `this` is different for each object with a lock each, they are independent of each other. In other words, it doesn't do anything in your case.